# Forge Prize Box contents and drop rates?

Tags: spiral-knights

Forge Prize Boxes are a new feature as of the July 30 patch and I'm having a hard time finding documentation on what exactly they contain.  The [wiki page](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Heat) isn't very helpful:

> Forge Prize Box containing a random assortment of various rarities and other items (prize box and contents are bound)

Could anyone who has been playing share a record of what has dropped and how often, or otherwise link to someone who has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forge boxes appear to be ranked according to the star level of the item forged to obtain it.

They hold a random assortment of:

- Sparks of life
- Fire Crystals (of the same tier as the box)
- Alchemy orbs
- UV tickets (1, 2, or 3UVs)

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying.  So it sounds like there are different tiers of prize boxes that parallel their heat crystal contents? Cool.  Feel free to update the answer if you get more data from your guildmates!

Comment: @HyperAnthony Yes, it does appear that way. And I will! :)

Comment: I was so dissapointed when I realized there were no Forge costumes or accessories in the box :C

Answer (score 0):

Ive got 2 boxes so far and each time it's been a 2 uv ticket, not sure if 1 or 3 drop. I've only heard of 2 variants dropping as well. Also, I don't think theres tiers for boxes like shining and warm, only the radiant forge box. Also I have only received boxes while crafting 5 star items, not sure if there are drops for 4 star or below. I got one prize box while Defender Elite and 1 as a Vanguard, so i can confirm non vanguards can receive prize boxes at least. Defender Elite I think I got 100 shining fire crystals, 2 uv ticket, 10 sparks, and I think a pet food (power orb) but Im not 100%. Vanguard i got 15 sparks, 50 Radiant fire, a 2 uv ticket, and an eternal orb of alchemy. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a shining box and got 12 sparks, 1 advanced orb, 2 variant, and 50 shining fire

Answer (score -1):

I have got 1 forge prize box so far, from crafting a blitz needle
I got a 2 UV ticket, sparks of life, a few hundred radiant crystals and 3 elite orbs